# UITapGestureRecognizer responding to incorrect UIView

Tags: swift, uiview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a 100x600 `UIView` sitting on top of the main `UIView` in a `ViewController`.  Normally, I want to keep this view hidden.  When the user taps on one of several controls, including the main view, I unhide the sub `UIView`.  Tapping anywhere on the main `UIView` will hide it.

In viewDidLoad, I have the following UITapGestureRecognizer:

```
    let viewTouch = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "viewClicked:")
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(viewTouch)
```

The viewClicked function looks like this:

```
func viewClicked(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    handleDisplayOfDropdownView()
}
```

The handleDisplayOfDropdown function is responsible for showing and hiding the sub `UIView`.  All it does is adjust the alpha of the subview, so that it is either visible or not visible.

```
func handleDisplayOfDropdownView() {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {
        if !self.dropDownVisible {
            self.dropDownVisible = true
            self.dropDownView.alpha = 1.0
        }
        else {
            self.dropDownVisible = false
            self.dropDownView.alpha = 0
        }
    })
}
```

All of the UI work is done by storyboard.  I just have a 100x600 view placed at the top of the ViewController.  It is made visible and hidden by tapping on the main UIView.

The problem that I'm having is that the sub `UIView` disappears when I tap on it.  When I set up the `UITapGestureRecognizer`, I figured that only a tap on the main `UIView` would activate and hide it.  It seems that tapping anywhere, including the sub `UIView` is hiding it.

Am I setting up the `UITapGestureRecognizer` incorrectly?

Comment: You need to check wether the touch point coming with in the frame of subView or not. If yes hide it subview else unhide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add gestureDelegate:

```
 UIGestureRecognizerDelegate
```

In ViewDidLoad set viewTouch UITapGesture delegate:

```
viewTouch.delegate = self
```

Then call this delegate

```
func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceiveTouch touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
    let p = touch.locationInView(view)
    if CGRectContainsPoint(dropDownView.frame, p) {
      return false
    }
    return true
  }
```

Comment: Works perfectly.  Thanks.  I did make one minor modification to gestureRecognizer.  I added the following:

       ` if !dropDownVisible {
            return true
        }`
        
This allows me to tap the area that the view is in and bring it up, but only if the view isn't currently being shown.

Thanks for the help!